# Storing a value in an if statment and using in elseif statement

Tags: php, if-statement

How do I store a value that's created in an if statement so I can use the same value in an elseif statement?

```
if (empty($_POST)) {
   $a = $b
}
else if ($_POST['ok'] == 'ok) {
   $c = 5
   echo $b . $c
```

I'd like to be able to store the value because each time the user hits a button, my page refreshes and the old values are refreshed too.  I'd like to keep a certain value regardless if the user happens to press that "OK" button so that my code doesn't completely refresh.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a SESSION variable.
It remains when the page is reloaded.
For example:

```
$_SESSION['my_variable']
```

Just don't forget to add `session_start();` at the top of your PHP file.

OBS: it seems to me that your problem is not keeping the value from an if statement, but rather on how to keep them when the page is reloaded

Comment: Can I store than one variables in the session?

Comment: @user2625145 Yes, `$_SESSION` is an array.

Comment: @user2625145 sure... you can have, for example, `$_SESSION['a']`, `$_SESSION['b']`,  `$_SESSION['c']`, ...